# Waterline unique validation not detected until the next sailsjs server reset

Tags: express, sails.js, waterline

I am using sails@beta.

I am trying to create several Room models (see definition) below, the problem is that I can successfully create Room models with the same attribute 'name', although attribute 'name' has a unique validation.

**The validation isn't detected until the next restart of 'sails' server**, then I get this output:

```
C:\eMali_dev\server>sails lift

info: Starting app...

Express midleware for passport
Waterline encountered a fatal error when trying to perform the `alter` auto-migration strategy.
In a couple of seconds, the data (cached in memory) will be logged to stdout.
(a failsafe put in place to preserve development data)

In the mean time, here's the error:

Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error:
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: eMali_beta_dev.room.$name_1  dup key: { : "e1" }
Details:
{ error: 'E_UNKNOWN',
  summary: 'Encountered an unexpected error',
  status: 500,
  raw: 'MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: eMali_beta_dev.room.$name_1  dup key: { : "e1" }' }


================================
Data backup:
================================

[ { name: 'e1',
    center: '53471e2318b931dc1b69f3a8',
    min_age: 1,
    max_age: 6,
    createdAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    updatedAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'SG\u001e#\u001811Ü\u001bióc' } },
  { name: 'e2',
    center: '53471e2318b931dc1b69f3a8',
    min_age: 1,
    max_age: 7,
    createdAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    updatedAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'SG\u001e#\u001811Ü\u001bióª' } },
  { name: 'e1',
    center: '53471e2318b931dc1b69f3a8',
    min_age: 1,
    max_age: 6,
    createdAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    updatedAt: Fri Apr 11 2014 00:41:39 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
    _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'SG\u001e#\u001811Ü\u001bió«' } } ]
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
```

Room model:

```
module.exports = {

    schema: true,

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            minLength: 3
        },

        center: {
            model: 'center'
        },

        min_age: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true
        },

        max_age: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in sails and it was fixed. Thanks everybody

Comment: it was fixed and broke again in later versions, it is not fixed.

Comment: I'm happy to hear I'm not the only one with this issue. Let's start a revolution and get this thing fixed!

Comment: for now you can add a workaround check by adding Model.find() check in BeforeUpdate and BeforeCreate functions in the model.js

Comment: I hope I don't have to add this kind of hack just to make model validation work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the database from default Disk database to a database of your choice.
I was facing a similar problem and changing database from "Disk" to "MongoDB" fixed my issue.
It seems the default database is unable to enforce unique constraint.

I hope it solves your issue.